# WebApi 2.0 OData, obtain list of SQL tables used in the query

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a fairly standard WebApi 2.0 OData 4.0 webservice using EF5, and code first approach. This service works and I can query entities and related entities through foreign keys.

The service is read-only and the controllers only have a Get and Get-by-key implemented.

```
public class MyTableController : MyDbController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<MyTable> Get()
    {
        return db.MyTable;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<MyTable> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        IQueryable<MyTable> result = db.MyTable.Where(p => p.pk == key);
        return SingleResult.Create(result);
    }
}
```

In both Get() implementations, I would like to have access to the list of tables that are being used in the OData and resulting SQL query. MyTable is obviously one of them, but how do I obtain the others (among others, the ones used in (nested) $expand)? I can try to parse the URL myself, but that's doesn't seem like a very good way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a class CustomizeAttribute inherit from EnableQueryAttribute
2. Override this method : `public virtual IQueryable ApplyQuery`
3. then you get the queryOptions in this method, you can go to the SelectExpandQueryOption and find the ExpandItem, then you get all the table.

   ```
   public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
   {
       if (queryOptions.SelectExpand != null)
       {
           foreach (var selectItem in queryOptions.SelectExpand.SelectExpandClause.SelectedItems)
           {
               var expandedItem = selectItem as ExpandedNavigationSelectItem;
               if (expandedItem != null)
               {
                   // get the entitySetName, tableName
                   string entitySetName = expandedItem.NavigationSource.Name;
                  // can go recursive with expandItem.SelectExpandClause in case we have $epxand=A($expand=B)
               }
           }
       }
       return base.ApplyQuery(queryable, queryOptions);
   }
   ```
4. Use this attribute on Controller method

   ```
   [CustomizeAttribute]
   public IQueryable<MyTable> Get()
   {
       return db.MyTable;
   }
   ```